# best way to get the max rect size

Tags: java, math, area

Let say if divide the box into 10 equal parts. I want to store in a array based on the each peice is greyed or not. If it is greyed then i put true otherwise false. Now, how should i program to determine the first large rectanglur grey area and second large rectangular grey area and third ..so on. . In this example, 2,4,6 forms a larger rectangular area and 7,8 forms smaller rectangular area.

boolean[] flag = new boolean[10];

[image]

[image]

Example: If 0 represents not grey and 1 represents grey

```
rect[0][0] = 0;
rect[0][1] = 0;
rect[0][2] = 0;
rect[0][3] = 1;
rect[0][4] = 1;
rect[1][0] = 1;
rect[1][1] = 1;
rect[1][2] = 1;
rect[1][3] = 0;
rect[1][4] = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        if( isGrey(rect[x][y])
            {
         flag[count] = true;
           } else {
         flag[count] = false;
      } 
      count ++;


   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "determine"?  What is the required output in this example?

Comment: Well, if the booleans are in an array, that doesn't really represent rectangles. This array would have every other position 'on' until 6, then it would have two on, one off, one on, and one off. That doesn't translate into rectangles. How are you mapping an arbitrary array to rectangles in code?

Comment: " 7,8 forms smaller rectangular area. " 7,8 or 7,9??